# Unity3D - ray.direction is on one side and hit.point on the other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So I'm juste trying to create a simple shoot system and the trying to get the hit of the raycast but it's giving me a point opposite to the direction of the ray.
So the code that's creating the ray cast :
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvuvt.png)

And here is [The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXUmE.png).

I'm missing something probably obvious but I cant find what.

Comment: From another angle it looks like sometime with the hit point the ray go way up or way down.

Answer (score 0):

So I was just using the wrong function to draw a ray to a point. DrawRay uses the direction, instead I should have use DrawLine which takes the hit.point.

[image]